# Is it really a standard to always include a Fact table into creating an OLAP Cube using SSAS?

Tags: sql-server, ssas-2008

Can I create a Cube by just combining Dimension Tables? Let's say I don't have a Fact table from the data sources and I want to create an OLAP cube out of the Dimensions that I have in the Database Tables sources.

I am studying SSAS only by myself and I saw from these examples (LINK) that building an OLAP cube requires a Fact table.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/658912/Create-First-OLAP-Cube-in-SQL-Server-Analysis-Serv

http://www.slideshare.net/PeterGfader/07-olap-5287936

The links above are very informative and helpful. However, I dont see any Fact table that I can link on the Dimension tables from the Data sources that I have.

Comment: I've never heard of creating a cube without one.  Your dimensions are ways of grouping together the transactional data contained within your fact table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As JaneD said in a comment I have also never heard of a cube without a fact table. The fact table(s) should include the numbers you want to play with/analyse/report on, your measures. The dimension will be used to slice and dice these measures in order to see f.ex number of sold items (a fact) in Europe (dimension) in 2012 (dimension).

If you only have regions and time, as in my example, you won't be able to do much with it. And if you're trying to learn SSAS you really should try to find/create a fact table so you can explore more of SSAS.